# Create a searchable form in Play Framework with Java

Tags: java, forms, performance, playframework

I'm trying to create something similar to the below HTML form using Play framework with Java:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

But instead of hard-coding the selectable values to be searched (like "Adele" in the example I gave above), I plan on querying a large dataset with thousands or 10s of thousands of records and allowing users to search that dataset. **Please answer my below 2 questions:**

1. Is this possible to do in the Play Framework
2. Would doing this be bad practice? Would it be better to have users enter a string and only query when they hit the 'Search' button?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is 100% possible with Play! The bottleneck will be your dataset. Is it a file, an SQL database, a nosql database, a search engine, a webservice query. This is where the problem usually lies.
2. Debatable. Implement it any way you like, if you experience bottlenecks tweak it. You could implement a 200ms timeout before firing the ajax request. A very nice tool is [select2](https://select2.org/) which allows you to easily configure this.

Comment: Great to know, I think I'll try to build the searchable select list and see how the performance is and tweak as necessary. select2 is EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up question? If I build it so that users can search by typing (as in the HTML form in my question), I'm trying to decide between 2 solutions: 1) Query the entire dataset on the load of a particular page. If I do this, should I store the result in the browser cache? 2) Each time a user has at least 2 characters entered in the search box && each time they change a letter, query the database. This would be a lot of queries though. What do you think?

Comment: This is a very broad question. I would really concentrate on actually creating something and then optimize as I go. 1) Storing results in the browser cache will not help your application at all to be honest. It's the server where the caching actually occurs. 2) Debatable. This really depends on what you want to do. The less times the DB is queried the better. But sometimes you have no way around it.